# In python, what is the optimal way to implement "debug mode" functions which only run conditionally (e.g. if app is in dev mode), but skips otherwise?

Tags: python, debugging, testing

I am currently developing (Python 2.7) a device which does fairly complex imaging work with a stereo camera rig on a Raspberry Pi. The functionality isn't particularly relevant to this post, however the fact that we are limited to a Pi's processing power while doing costly operations is very relevant.

The device is governed by one central class, which I'll call *BaseClass*, where most of the functionality lives, however it is instantiated in one of two subclasses which extend it: *DeviceClass*, which is instantiated when the device itself is booting up, and *DesktopClass* which is instantiated on a computer, and contains functions and overrides as needed in order to emulate the exact same functionality as we get on the Pi - essentially, it is used to streamline the development process.

Often times the code does image manipulation and remapping, and I want to save the image in between steps to confirm that everything looks the way it should. I want this functionality to be toggleable based on a parameter you set on instantiation, without having to constantly change code, and only in *DesktopClass*. There are many ways to get this functionality, *however*, most of them involve conditionals or leveraging polymorphism, which either sacrifice unnecessary clock cycles when run on the device (bad, because of limited processing power), or lead to repetitive code in separate classes with only a couple lines changed, which I want to avoid just as much to keep the codebase clean.

**So the question is, is there a way to create this functionality in such a way that I can have a single call which outputs the debug code (e.g. displaying an image) when the development mode is enabled, but simply skips without wasting any extra clock cycles when not in development mode, as might be achieved with macros or something else in a compiled language?**

*NOTE: This is also not the best example because compared to an image manipulation, a function call which returns immediately or a conditional is practically negligible. However there are other cases where I will want to call similar debug functions on a much more granular level, where it could add a nonnegligible overhead.*

---

For example, in the following code, I have a function which does several successive image operations using functions that are the same on desktop and device, so it is defined in *BaseClass* and defining it in the subclasses would be wasteful. In desktop mode however, I want to save the images between each step if self.dev is True.

```
class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dev = False

    def imaging(self, img_list, map_a, map_b):

        imgsout = []

        for img in img_list:
            # Do some image remapping
            step1 = cv2.remap(img, map_a[0], map_a[1])

            #DEBUG SAVE IMAGE

            step2 = cv2.remap(step1, map_b[0], map_b[1])

            #DEBUG SAVE IMAGE

            imgsout.append(step2)

        return imgsout


class DesktopClass(BaseClass):

    def __init__(self, dev=False):
        BaseClass.__init__(self)
        self.dev = dev

class DeviceClass(BaseClass):

    def __init__(self):
        BaseClass.__init__(self)


# Body code

# Bunch of images to work on, doesn't matter what this is
imgs = [img1, img2, img3]

# This code runs on the desktop development setting
desktop = DesktopClass(dev=True)
output1 = desktop.imaging(imgs, map_a, map_b)
# When stepping through this code, I should save the intermediary images several steps

desktop.dev = False
output2 = desktop.imaging(imgs, map_a, map_b)
# This code should run without saving any images but give the same output


# This code runs on the raspberry pi
device = DeviceClass()
output3 = desktop.imaging(imgs, map_a, map_b)
# This code should run without saving any images but give the same output
```

Some potential solutions and their shortcomings:

1. Define a class function BaseClass.debug_saveim() which checks self.dev is True before executing any debug code.

   - Pros: Single line for each debug call in the base class - doesn't clutter the code significantly, functionality is obvious at first glance and doesn't hurt readability of code.
   - Cons: On the device, enters a new function just to fail a conditional and exit. Relatively wasteful when trying to do stuff in realtime.
2. Define a class function BaseClass.saveim() which saves the image. Every time it is used in the imaging() function (or elsewhere), wrap it in a conditional so that it only runs if in dev mode

   - Pros: Avoids entering a new function stack frame on device, only has to do the conditional which is more efficient
   - Cons: Clutters the code. Requires two lines for a single function which doesn't even execute on the intended, final product. Hurts readability and honestly just looks bad. Still wastes a tiny bit of time with a conditional.
3. Define DesktopClass.imaging() separately from BaseClass.imaging(), where the base one has no debug calls, and the desktop one overrides it.

   - Pros: Device never wastes any cycles because the debug calls don't even exist in that context
   - Cons: Redundant code, and all the bad things that come with it.
4. Define an identically named debug function separately such as BaseClass.debug_save_im() and DesktopClass.debug_save_im(). These pass without doing anything, and save the image, respectively. This function is called in BaseClass.imaging().

   - Pros: One very readable line per debug output, doesn't clutter code. Leverages polymorphism without using any redundant code. Elegant.
   - Cons: Still has to enter a new function in the device context, even if it just passes. Have to write two definitions per debug function.

**Is there a standard, or commonly accepted practice to get this functionality as efficiently as possible? Is there a tool or library which does this as effectively as possible?**

Thank you!

*P.S. I know python is very suboptimal for any sort of realtime operation, but we have our reasons for using it, and truth be told having conditionals and whatnot probably won't hurt out operation at all, but it still feels dirty on principle, and I would very much like to know if there is a clean and elegant solution that also optimizes performance.*

Comment: `logging.Logger` can have its own log level and `Logger.isEnabledFor` can test whether a level is enabled. Moreover, loggers have hierarchy structure.

Comment: This does not answer my question. Logger is great and good for writing clean code, but I am more concerned about optimal performance on the release branch, i.e. debug functions that save as many clock cycles as possible when the device is *not* in debug mode.